# Correct use of C# Generics in a Repository Concrete class

Tags: c#, generics, couchbase

Am attempting to create a `C#` Repository Class which uses Generics to access a `Couchbase` database. The code for the add and read look like this...

```
public void Add<T>(string id, T entity) where T : class
{
    var doc = new Document<T>()
    {
        Id = id,
        Content = entity
    };

    activeBucket.Upsert(doc);
    return;
}

public T Read<T>(string id)
{
    var result = activeBucket.GetDocument<T>(id);
    return result;
}
```

The Add function works fine, my problem is with the Read and returning the result which has a cast issue along the lines of:

```
Cannot implicitly convert Couchbase.IDocumentResult<T> to T
```

I understand why this is the case, have had several attempts to resolve, all to no avail.

Any help really appreciated, it's driving me a little crazy.

Thanks,

Shaun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the [documents](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-net-client-2.1.0/html/c26bc9fc-294e-06af-2df0-4c4e50d6870a.htm) correctly, you'd just return `Content`, since the document object is just a wrapper around the content with some extra data about the result of the request:

```
return result.Content;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, that works perfectly, am kicking myself as makes complete sense. Really appreciate your help.